# In a field, $a \mapsto a^2$ is bijective. Then the characteristic is..?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Exercise 31 (page 16) in Golan - The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Ought to Know (3rd Edition):

> Let $F$ be a field satisfying the condition that the function $a \mapsto a^2$ is a permutation of $F$. What is the characteristic of $F$?

I am not able to answer, but I managed to do *something*.

If $p$ is a prime integer and $F = \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$ (so that the characteristic is $p$), I can prove (or at least I think) that

> $p = 2 \iff a \mapsto a^2 \text{ is bijective}$

One direction is obvious, while for the other I just note that $[(p-1)^2]_p = [1^2]_p$ so that, if $p>2$, $a \mapsto a^2$ is not injective.

When it comes to more general cases, I would like some hints from you.

Comment: If the function $a\mapsto a^2$ is injective then $a=-a$ for every $a$...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $a\mapsto a^2$ is a permutation, then $1^2\neq(-1)^2$ *unless* $1=-1$. But, on the other hand, you always have $1^2=(-1)^2$. Therefore, $1=-1$. In other words, the characteristic is $2$.

Comment: All clear - thank you!